# Access admin page

Tags: php, session, authentication, admin

Hi Im trying to create a admin login. In my, mysql database, in the table 'users_table' I have the field admin and its default value = N but if it equals Y then direct it the Admin.php
here is my current code for starting a new session and I was wondering if I could put it in there so that if it does = Y then say session 'Admin' starts and redirects to Admin.php instead of $_SESSION['name'] (btw 'name' is field 1 in my database and field 'admin' is 7

```
    <?php
session_start();
    include ('condb.php');

   $name = $_POST ['username'];
   echo $name;
   $query ="SELECT name FROM users_table WHERE (name = '$name')" ;
   $result = mysql_query($query)
    or die (mysql_error($con)); 
 $row= mysql_num_rows($result);  
 if ($row=1){
 $_SESSION['name'] = $row[1];
  }         
    ?>
```

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: woah ... read [PHP MySQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apart from the obligatory SQL injection, what have you tried? This says "here is my code, fix it". Please read a (recent) PHP + MySQL tutorial, which will point you towards PDO. Really, give it a read.

In the meantime, something like this might work:

```
$rowcount = mysql_num_rows($result);
if ($rowcount == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    $_SESSION['name'] = $row['name'];
    if ($row['admin'] == 'Y')
    {
        $_SESSION['admin'] = $row['admin'];
        header("Location: admin.php");
        exit();
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry im new at all this. ill do that in the future

Comment: @user1450791 in the future is too late ... read it before you start else you will be re-writing all of your code ... i suggest you [start here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pdo.php)